# Data Factory The value of the property 'Value' is invalid for the stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory, uniqueidentifier

I have an ADF pipeline where I have a variable 'ParameterName' with datatype String.
[image]

This one is filled with a SQL lookup where I have tried:

SELECT CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(50)) AS ParameterName
and
SELECT NEWID() AS ParameterName

[image]

After that I set the variable with:

@activity('Get ParameterName').output.firstRow.ParameterName

[image]

But when I later try to use this as a parameter for a stored procedure (with datatype GUID) it returns an error. I take as value for the parameter: @variables('ParameterName').

The stored procedure is expecting a parameter with datatype UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.

[image]

And it seems that the datatype gives issues because I receive this error:

Cannot create Sql Source. Please double check the connection string, stored procedure are set with correct format. Error: The value of the property 'Value' is invalid for the stored procedure parameter 'ParameterName'.

[image]

So the question is; how to fix this? I can update Stored Proc to let it accept varchar instead of uniqueidentifier but that is not what I prefer. I would like to align datatypes in Data Factory to the type SQL expects it to be.

Somebody has an idea what is the case here?

Comment: I have tried something similar (SELECT NEWID() AS ParameterName) and passed the value to my stored procedure (as GUID) and this worked without issues. Can you check if you are able to make a successful connection to your sql resource?

Comment: What do you mean with a succesful connection? I am able to copy data to the same database as where the stored proc is in. So if that's what you mean; that's not the issue.

But you did a SELECT NEWID() you say. That was a string as well I guess?

Comment: I fixed it. It seemed that my pipeline sometimes took a direction where I ended up with a NULL value. That was all :(